# How i can return records there are not null only if a column have a determined value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to make a query that verify:

if `type_answer` is equal to `Multipla Escolha` so i only have to return the records that are not null in `correct_answer_description_id`
If the `type_answer` is not equal to `Multipla Escolha`, don’t make this rule.

So, i try this way:

```
SELECT * FROM book_unit_question
WHERE book_unit_id = 2 
AND status = false
CASE WHEN type_answer = 'Multipla Escolha' THEN
correct_answer_description IS NOT NULL
```

but i'm getting:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CASE"
```

Comment: `and not (type_answer = 'Multipla Escolha' and correct_answer_description IS NULL)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think CASE is the easiest approach here.  Can you try the re-written query below?

```
SELECT * FROM book_unit_question
WHERE book_unit_id = 2 
AND status = false
AND (type_answer is null or type_answer != 'Multipla Escolha' or
correct_answer_description IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of the negative yields negative construct "type_answer is not equal to Multipla Escolha, don’t make this rule" by rephrasing "type answer equal Multipla Escolha then apply this rule. Also applying "only return the records that are not null in correct_answer_description_id". We arrieve at:

```
select * 
  from book_unit_question
 where book_unit_id = 2 
   and status = false
   and type_answer = 'Multipla Escolha' 
   and correct_answer_description is not null;
```

Comment: I also need the records that don't have the type_answer <> 'Multipla Escolha'